# Exported shapes as image with vba in powerpoint with a white space in the button and top

Tags: image, vba, export, powerpoint

I want to export certain shapes in powerpoint as images. For that I am using the following code:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).Export "C:\dink_template\created_files\testimg.jpg", ppShapeFormatJPG
```

I also tried with other image formats:

```
 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).Export "C:\dink_template\created_files\testimg.png", ppShapeFormatPNG
```

and I get this image:

[image]

Here you cannot notice because the white peace that appears in the image button (and also a bit in the top) is mixing with the page but if you make inspect element on the photo you will see it.

As you can see in this other image in powerpoint the shape fix perfectly and it is not bigger that the image:

[image]

Why is appearing this white peace in the top and in the button? How can I export the image without them?

EDIT
I know when it is happening. Because I try with other ones and sometimes they where not appearing and sometime it was. The problem is that when the text you write in the shape is so close to the border and you export it as image it export with this white space. Now the question is... how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to adjust the size of your shape and/or the size of the text accordingly to the total text length, before exporting it as an image, in order to make sure that your text will never be too close to the border...

Something else: have you checked the margins properties of your shape? Putting them to 0 might help a bit.